# Can bluetooth USB adapter affect sound quality of headphones?

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I have SB EVO Wireless headphones, and a cheap $2 unnamed bluetooth USB adapter in my desktop PC (I know, funny combination, but the USB adapter worked with no problem (i.e. with cell phone) until I started using wireless headphones.

There are several problems with it:
- sometimes the headphones don't pair automatically after turning on, I have to remove and re-add them to bluetooth devices list (Windows 8)
- the sound is generally quite low quality
- sometimes i.e. during Skype call, when another application tries to play a sound (just windows "asterisk" sound sometimes causes it), only noise can be heard for several seconds, making impossible to call over skype.

My question is, can such problems be caused by the cheap bluetooth USB adapter? Does it make sense to buy better one, or is the problem anywhere else? thanks.

Please tell me if you need more information about my PC configuration, I don't even have idea what kind of information would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it was really caused by poor bluetooth adapter, today I bought Creative Bluetooth Audio BT-D1 USB and now the sound is perfectly clear, even with skype call and listening to music at once.

Answer (score 1):

It could be other environmental factors causing interference.

Generally so long as the USB adapter is the same bluetooth version (4.0 for example) it should work well with all 4.0 devices since it is a standard. A cheaper one may have a lower range or rather more expensive ones might have improved range/connectivity over the standard.

How far away are you from the adapter? Is there anything blocking the line of sight? Could you use a USB extension cable to bring the adapter closer to the headphones?

Are there other devices connected to the adapter as well?

Comment: Thanks for answer.
- I'm about 50cm from the adapter, that shouldn't be problem
- there is nothing blocking the adapter, no other connected devices.
maybe the problem is that the adapter is lower than bluetooth 4.0 (how can I determine that on W8?)